# AWS s3 list only the folder names from the bucket

Tags: bash, ls, aws

I have an s3 bucket that contains folders inside it with the date prefixes. For example-

```
bucket_name
    --> 2021-11-01
    --> 2021-11-02
    --> 2021-11-03
    --> 2021-11-04
           ...
           ...
    --> 2021-11-10
```

The idea is, I need to clean up the whole folder with the objects that reside inside it if it is 7 days old. So I need to find only the **folder names inside that bucket** to check the date of it and delete the content inside it.

**Full Code:**

```
aws s3 ls s3://$S3_PATH/ | while read -r line;  do
    # Get file creation date
    createDate=`echo $line|awk {'print $1" "$2'}`
    createDate=`date -d"$createDate" +%s`

     if [[ $createDate -lt $DELETETION_TIMESTAMP ]]
     then
         # Get file name
         FILENAME=`echo $line|awk {'print $4'}`
         if [[ $FILENAME != "" ]]
           then
             echo "   -> Deleting $FILENAME"
             aws s3 rm --recursive s3://S3_PATH/$createDate/
         fi
     fi
done;
```

**Error:** If I do `echo $createDate`

> date: invalid date ‘PRE 2021-11-01/’

**EDIT:**

```
echo $line
```

returns

```
PRE 2021-11-01/
2021-11-01 15:10:15 0
```

Comment: bacticks for command substitution are deprecated `\`...\``, use the modern `$(...)` instead.

Comment: Do `echo "$line"` first to see what you are parsing with `awk`.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity please check my edit on what $line returns

Comment: (Besides other problems that may or not occur) you can use `grep -om1 '[0-9\-]*'` instead of the `awk` command, which will give you `2021-11-01` as result. Also use [`while IFS= read -r line`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385772/bash-read-line-by-line-from-file-with-ifs).